# "Delete scheduled tasks" not firing

Tags: rules

I have done the following:

1. rule component with action send email notification.
2. rule that schedule the component "after saving a content".

When I go to schedule I can see that the rule fires the scheduled component and when I execute it.. the email sent successfully.

I have created another rule with Event "after updating existing content" and "Delete scheduled tasks" as action to cancel the component above.

[image]

But unfortunately it doesn't work.. and when I go to schedule nothing appears for canceling the task.

Any help?